# Can I connect to 2 layers of authentification on the same domaine?

Tags: reactjs, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-fargate

I am building an ERP and I decided to deploy it on AWS. I already coded my frontend in REACT and my backend in python Django. They are both Dockerized and I will deploy them with on ECS Fargate and with PostgreSQL on ECR. All of this contained in a VPC.

I want to create 1 VPC per client/company with their own pool of users authenticated with either Django or cognito. I'm not sure yet.

But I am wondering if I can have a landing page with my domain name where clients would be signing in with a cognito pool, giving them access to their respective VPC  in a subdomain. And then signing in as a user in that VPC on a different sub-pool. Won't I have a token conflict being on the same domain?

I think having those 2 layers of auth would avoid chances of having clients accessing the wrong database.
(example: new user created in the wrong pool)

This is my first post, although I use this forum a lot. I hope it is clear. Let me know if you need more details

thanks

Update: so it seems I'm trying to do a multi-tenant application. I made I diagram to show what I am going for. The setup for each individual VPC, I'm almost done and got a good idea how to implement it. It's the top part that can't wrap my head around.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owP5u.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be not "two layers of authentication".

You should authenticate users with Cognito only once and assign authenticated users an IAM role. This IAM role and policies linked to it are used to control user access to different AWS resources.

There are several ways to achieve this. Some of them are depending on AWS service quotas, overall application and service arhcitectures etc.

You may find this AWS document useful: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/multi-tenant-application-best-practices.html

If you are able to provide a conceptual architecture diagram with all the AWS resources you are intending to use, there will be a change that you receive more detailed answers.